# How to show number of courses a student failed

Tags: sql, count

I have code already that shows the students who have failed a course, but I would also like to show the number of courses that student failed.

Here's the code I have at the moment:

```
SELECT s.studentid, s.name
FROM student s
INNER JOIN notes ON s.studentid = notes.studentid
WHERE notes.note <  "50"
ORDER BY student.name
```

I have three tables.

student:

```
| studentid | name |
```

notes:

```
| studentid | note | courseid |
```

and course:

```
| courseid |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Aggregate function** `Count()`

```
SELECT s.studentid, s.name,notes.courseid ,count(1) CNT
FROM student s
INNER JOIN notes ON s.studentid = notes.studentid
WHERE (notes.note) <  "50"
group by s.studentid, s.name, notes.courseid
ORDER BY student.name
```

Comment: this only shows me how many students failed a course, I want to know how many courses each student failed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this already has an answer, but I would like to offer a different perspective:

Since you have the studentid and courseid in the notes table, you can grab everything you want from that table:

```
SELECT studentid, COUNT(*) AS numFailedCourses
FROM notes
WHERE note < 50
GROUP BY studentid
```

This will select all rows from the notes table with a failing grade, and by grouping by student id. If you really do need the student name, however, you still need to join the students table, which is the same as the answer that's already given:

```
SELECT s.studentid, s.name, COUNT(*) AS numFailedCourses
FROM notes n
JOIN students s ON s.studentid = n.studentid
WHERE n.note < 50
GROUP BY s.studentid
ORDER BY s.name
```